# In Datagrid tab to auto scroll to out of view DataGridTemplateColumns

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a `DataGrid` which is made up of a bunch of `DataGridTemplateColumns`. Sometimes the width of the form is small enough that it doesn't show all columns at the same time. I would like to be able to tab to the next column and have it automatically scroll to the right if needed to show the next column. This seems to work great if I use a built-in column type, like `DataGridTextColumn`. But when using template columns if I tab to go to the next column which is out of view then sometimes it will tab to it and I can set the value (even though the control is still out of view). Other times I can't even set the value.

Is there a way around this limitation? Is it a bug with Avalonia? Maybe I need to create my own custom DataGridColumn type and it will work like the built in ones?

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="AvaloniaDataGridTabbing.Views.MainView"
  xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AvaloniaDataGridTabbing.Views"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaDataGridTabbing.ViewModels"
  d:DesignHeight="450"
  d:DesignWidth="400"
  x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Design.DataContext>
    <!--
      This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
      to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs)
    -->
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>


  <DataGrid
    Name="datagrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{CompiledBinding Users}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Title">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="250" Text="{CompiledBinding Title}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <NumericUpDown
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Maximum="120"
              Minimum="0"
              Value="{CompiledBinding Age}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Name">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="250" Text="{CompiledBinding Name}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Address">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="250" Text="{CompiledBinding Address}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Phone Number">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Width="250" Text="{CompiledBinding PhoneNumber}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Before tabbing]
[image: After tabbing]